Stuck at 640x480 resolution and Intel not loading i915
After booting up I was met with a black screen. I was able to access the command line and after changing the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT (now I don't remember if I added nomodeset or removed it), I got a low resolution display at 640x480.
I search online and tried to used ubuntu-drivers to no avail. Then by running inxi (check the output bellow) I inferred that the issue must be with my integrated card not loading the i915 driver.
I know it's not an hardware problem because I booted Ubuntu 24 from a live USB and there was no resolution problem and i915was loading properly. For references I've copied the output of inxi in the same system with the live USB Ubuntu (see bellow)
I don't know much about Linux and I don't know if the issue might be of some X server vs Wayland issue because I tried to have both installed so that I could change between them; or some display manager issue.
I would be really grateful for any help, this system has proprietary software so I would like to avoid a clean install.
Update: I was able see the Ubuntu logo and then I got to a black screen with visible cursor using Kernel 6.8.0-45-generic. If I go to the terminal and try to startx, I get an error
xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O port 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)
The surprising thing is that sudo startx works and leads me to the correct resolution.
Faulty system:
System:
  Host: joachim-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF
    Kernel: 6.11.0-061100-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Hewlett-Packard
    product: HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 1998
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Hewlett-Packard
    v: L01 v02.78 date: 02/20/2020
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i5-4570 bits: 64
    type: MCP cache: L2: 1024 KiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1095 min/max: 800/3600 cores: 1: 1987
    2: 798 3: 798 4: 800
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor
    Integrated Graphics driver: N/A
  Device-2: Sunplus Innovation HD 720P webcam
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo type: USB
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland
    v: 23.2.6 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: swrast gpu: N/A
    resolution: 640x480~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: kms_swrast,swrast
    platforms: gbm,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 vendor: mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1
    renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6 256 bits)

Live USB system:
System:
  Host: ubuntu Kernel: 6.8.0-41-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF
    v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 1998 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: Hewlett-Packard v: L01 v02.78 date: 02/20/2020
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i5-4570 bits: 64 type: MCP cache:
    L2: 1024 KiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1739 min/max: 800/3600 cores: 1: 1957 2: 1008 3: 800
    4: 3193
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics
    driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Sunplus Innovation HD 720P webcam driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
    type: USB
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: crocus gpu: i915 resolution:
    1: 1280x1024~60Hz 2: 1280x1024~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: crocus,swrast platforms: x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1
    renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)

Edit: Added the same inxi output on the same system with the Ubuntu from the live USB.

It may be an issue with a faulty but recent kernel update. First, check if installing all available updates fixes the issue. Otherwise, can you try going back to a previously installed kernel? https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version

What OS are you using? as your paste shows a non-Ubuntu kernel

@ArchismanPanigrahi I've tried to do a full update on the system and I changed between a older kernel.

@guiverc I'm running Ubuntu but during the time I was trying to solve the problem I installed a more recent kernel to see if it would fix the problem. Now I don't think it's a kernel version problem because while trying to fix the problem, I had the same kernel version of the live usb and my system had the problem while the live usb did not.

Don't forget then, by installing and using a non-supported kernel, all security fixes are on you to add to your system, as the provided kernel patches only work on the supported kernels (6.8 is GA for noble, and whilst 6.11 is the next HWE your kernel won't even benefit from those patches as you're not using the Ubuntu HWE kernel)

@guiverc I will revert to the supported kernel. I was just a bit desperate and trying all sorts of possibilities.

I found an answer that might be of use for the future. Eventually, I realized that the system was not booting to the login page. So I thought that it my be a problem with the display manager. So I switched to lightdm and back to gdm3 and it solved my problem:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3

For some reason, this only solved the problem in the 6.8.0-45-generic kernel. There might be additional problem in my current installation but I think they're beyond the scope of this question.
